# dynamically create a MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i generate a MVC application dynamically. I have a classlibary in this classlibary i generate a Controller code as a String. This string looks like:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XmlConfiguration;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using GenerateCode;
namespace Test{

public partial class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Home(){
        return View();
    }
}

namespace Test{

    public class RouteConfig{
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)    
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional });    
        }
    }
}
namespace Test{
    public class FilterConfig{
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)    
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());            
        }
    }
}
namespace Test{
    public class BundleConfig{
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)    
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")); 
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"));    
        }
    }
}
namespace Test{
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication   {
        protected void Application_Start()       
        {
           AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
           FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
           RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
           BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles); 
        }  
    }
}
```

I compile this error in a WPF application. I also generate a View.
My folder looks like

->bin-> with the dll and the oder dll for a MVC application

->Views->Home->Home.cshtml

->Views->_ViewStart.cshtml

->Views->WebConfig

->WebConfig

->Global.asax

I generated a new IIS Page after i put this folder into this IIS Page i don't get a Page displayed. I think the problem is the Global.asax file but how can i fix this Problem? 
Because the Global.asax file looks like :

`<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Test.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %`>

Comment: Probelm Solvend. Add a Application pool to the iis with the right .net  framework